# Apache mod_cache: Vary cache based on cookie values

Tags: apache, caching, cookies

Currently, I am using mod_cache to cache the page details of a web application.

I have the cache Vary based on User-Agent and Accept-Language, since there are different payloads for those situations.

```
Vary: User-Agent, Accept-Language
```

We have plans to have region-specific information on each page, but this is where we are trying to determine our caching strategy.

We have a cookie that persists to indicate the region we geolocated for, but obviously the cache does not vary based on this cookie.

It is possible to vary based on the **value** for certain cookies or headers in general? (Note I say certain cookies, as we wouldn't want the session identifier to collide with this) - something like a regex match to this:

```
location=(.+?);
```

Comment: In principle assume that there are no cookies on visitor`s PC - they may be disabled, deleted or something else. Another idea is to use geolocation, there are some free libs for php.

Answer (score 1):

That is possible using Apache. It can parse cookie value and pass it to custom header, then you need to Vary by this header:

```
# Set languageC cookie value to environment variable "siteLanguage"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^.*lunetics_locale.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} (?:^|;\s*)lunetics_locale=([^;]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [env=siteLanguage:%1]

# If no languageC cookie present. Set "siteLanguage" environment variable to "en"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*lunetics_locale.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [env=siteLanguage:en]

# Set enviroment variable "siteLanguage" value to custom header "SiteLanguage"
RequestHeader set X-Language "%{siteLanguage}e" env=siteLanguage
```

and add `Vary X-Language` to your response headers.
I'm not sure this is a best way, I have related question and problems with this: [Is it possible to vary page caches (to have cache versions) with the same url and different cookie value (language)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29907496/is-it-possible-to-vary-page-caches-to-have-cache-versions-with-the-same-url-an)