# Is it possible to vary page caches (to have cache versions) with the same url and different cookie value (language)?

Tags: caching, http-headers, browser-cache, reverse-proxy, varnish

We have a multilanguage site and want to cache e.g. page `/about`.
English and belarusian pages have the same URL: `/about`, language is stored in and detected from the cookies.

- En: `/about`, cookie: `site_lang: en`
- Be: `/about`, cookie: `site_lang: be`

We have a ReverseProxy cache (SymfonyHttp or Varnish).
When the first user opens the `/about` page with `en` value in cookies, it's cached by ReverseProxy and by browser.
Response headers:

```
Cache-Control max-age=600, public, s-maxage=600
Last-Modified Mon, 27 Apr 2015 21:48:34 GMT
Vary X-Language
...
```

### What is `X-Language`:

Since we can't vary by Cookies (it will lead to have different cache versions for each user because of at least session id), we vary by custom header that is set by Apache.

So when user made a GET request, Apache parses `site_lang` cookie and adds parsed value to custom header `X-Language`. With this logic, ReverseProxy knows what to do: just return cache or forward request to application if there is no cache for some language from this header.

It works when the second user opens the `/about` page with `be` value in cookies, Apache parses this language, creates `X-Language: be` header and ReverseProxy don't return cache for `en` language but forward request to application.

But it doesn't work when the first user tries to change locale with LocaleSwitcher on the site. When it tries to click to another language link, **browser** immediately returns local cached page and user's request is not processed by Apache, of course.

So my question, how to handle this situation, what are the possible solutions.
The main requirement is *we don't want to have language in the URL*.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize what Varnish uses for its hash key in the `vcl_hash` function, see [here](https://www.varnish-software.com/static/book/VCL_functions.html#vcl-vcl-hash).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But browser immediately returns a cached page and my request is not handled by Varnish/SymfonyReverseProxy.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to send a `Vary: Cookie` to the client because for the client, the response he gets depends on the cookie he sends. This will however not work if there are any other cookies like google analytics.

The other obvious alternative is to use the locale in the domain or the path, so en.mydomain.com/about or mydomain.com/en/about. This is also more friendly when people send links to pages as the language is part of the link.

In case your application is built with symfony, its no problem to change the strategy, and also to have one language that is the "default" and does not have the locale in the URL.

Comment: 1) `Vary: Cookie`: this will not work because of at least PHPSESSID, I've checked it :)
2) Yes, having the locale in the URL is the easiest way, but I wanted to avoid locale in the URLs. Seems like it's impossible to store locale in the cookie and use ReverseProxy...

Then I have the same question about FOSHttpCache UserContext - how does it work if server returns `Cache-Control max-age=600` and cache shoud be varied by `X-User-Context-Hash`.

As I understand, after the page is opened, it will be cached by browser for 600s and if the user changes its Role,browser will return the same cache,no?

Comment: if you do max-age, the browser will cache the page and not ask the server. so you need to set `Vary: Cookie` and make sure to [restart the session](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php) when the user logs in or logs out. this is a generally recommended for security. if you use symfony, see [this doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html) instead of using the native php functions. the request to change the locale will set a cookie, so it should never be cached.

Answer (score 0):

You might attempt to update the cookie using JavaScript before the HTTP request is sent. This means the `site_lang` cookie should not be encrypted and it should be accessible to JavaScript (do not set `HttpOnly`).